# Generalized quantors, how?

Tags: logic

Is there a "standard" form for a) a generalized existence quantor, assuring that there are at least n objects existing, b) a generalized forall quantor, allowing that n objects violate its assurance? Of course any such statement can be written with $\forall,\exists$. In any case I never saw a (say) $\forall^N$ in math literature yet, and googling didn't brought up anything (as usual, I probably just used the wrong search terms...)

Comment: See [Generalized Quantifiers](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/generalized-quantifiers/)

Comment: See also my answers to [Why haven't mathematicians come up with an efficient way of writing “sufficiently”, e.g. “for $n$ sufficiently large”](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2673906/13130) (a "stack exchange" version of [this 21 December 2004 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/sci.math/rhZEhXynVLQ/MI0MJ0ZQIvoJ)) and [Relations between the "$\forall$" quantifier and integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2796960/13130).

Comment: (waves finger) Original research :-) (I.e. I can't suppose the casual reader of my work is familiar with the notation.) But it didn't surprise me the concept already exists.