# Understanding the concept of infinitely often

Tags: probability, measure-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes, borel-cantelli-lemmas

My book in stochastic processes has this section about i.o which I don’t really understand. Is there any example of any other to explain this? How can I understand this?

It states the following:
Let $A_{1}, A_{2}, \ldots$ be a sequence of subsets of $\Omega$. We define
$$
\left(A_{n} \text { i.o. }\right)=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{m=n}^{\infty} A_{m}
$$
The abbreviation i.o. stands for infinitely often.

Comment: What exactly about the notion of infinitely often is confusing? Be mindful that infinity can have different meanings in different contexts

Comment: "$(A_n\text{ i.o. })$" strikes me as kind of a weird looking notation. I think I would have written it as $\Phi(A_1,A_2,\ldots)$ (the Greek $\Phi$ looking like a combination of "I" and "o"), or something along those lines. Does anyone know if "$(A_n\text{ i.o. })$" is a standard notation?

Comment: $(\text{$A_n$ i.o.})$ on its own is not, however $\{\text{$A_n$ i.o.}\}$ and $\mathbb P(\text{$A_n$ i.o.})$ are both frequently used in probability theory.

Comment: The term is often written as $$\limsup_{n\to \infty} A_n,$$ Never seen th “i.o.” notation before, but Wikipedia includes it. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit

Comment: @Barry Cipra and Thomas Andrews and others interested: *Does anyone know if* "($A_n$ *i.o. )" is a standard notation?* --- A notation I like is $\exists^{\infty}$ for "there exist infinitely many" and $\forall^{\infty}$ for "for all but finitely many". I discuss these a bit in my answer to [Why haven't mathematicians come up with an efficient way of writing “sufficiently”, e.g. “for $n$ sufficiently large”](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2673906/13130).

Answer (score 4):

Consider a point $x$. Then the point $x$ is in infinitely many of the sets $A_1, A_2, \ldots$ if and only if there exists no final $A_n$ containing $x$. This means for all $n$ there exists some $m \geq n$ such that $x \in A_m$. This is precisely the case when
$$ x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{m = n}^{\infty} A_m.$$
Thus $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{m = n}^{\infty} A_m$ is exactly the set of points which are in infinitely many of the $A_1, A_2, \ldots$